# TimescaleDB slower than plain postgresql 10 for insert

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, timescaledb

I am inserting 1m rows into a test table with timescale using JDBC and the performance seems to be about half that of plain postgresql. Timescale tuning was done by taking all values suggested by the timescale-tune utility. What am I doing wrong?

```
   private static void writeTable(String sql, int count, int commitCount,
   Connection conn) throws Exception
   {
       conn.setAutoCommit(false);
       long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
       long t = start;
       PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
       for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
       {
           stmt.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(t));
           stmt.setDouble(2, 10.9);
           stmt.addBatch();
           t ++;
           if(commitCount != -1 && ((i + 1) % commitCount) == 0)
           {
               stmt.executeBatch();
               conn.commit();
           }
       }
       stmt.executeBatch();
       stmt.close();
       conn.commit();
       conn.close();
       long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
       System.out.println("Count      : " + count);
       System.out.println("Total Time : " + diff);
       System.out.println("Writes/Sec : " + ((count * 1000) / diff));
   }
```

```
Query: INSERT INTO kt_device_info (di_device_id, di_time, di_value) VALUES (1,?,?)
```

```
Table:
CREATE TABLE kt_device (
    id              BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    d_name          TEXT
);

insert into kt_device(id, d_name) values (1, 'dev-1');

CREATE TABLE kt_device_info (
    di_device_id    BIGINT REFERENCES  kt_device NOT NULL,
    di_time         TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    di_value        DOUBLE PRECISION  NULL
);

SELECT create_hypertable('kt_device_info', 'di_time');
```

**Timescale** :
Count      : 1000000
Total Time : 42026
**Writes/Sec : 23794**

**Postgres 10:**
Count      : 1000000
Total Time : 22573
**Writes/Sec : 44300**

PostgreSQL 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-1.pgdg16.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit

timescaledb | 1.4.2   | public | Enables scalable inserts and complex queries for time-series data

Hardware:
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4702MQ CPU @ 2.20GHz, 16GB Memory

```
Chunks:
SELECT show_chunks('kt_device_info');
              show_chunks               
----------------------------------------
 _timescaledb_internal._hyper_7_7_chunk
(1 row)
```

Comment: Use `perf` to see in which function of which executable the time is spent. You'll need debugging symbols installed.

Comment: In TimescaleDB it is important to have right size of chunks. Can you check and add to the question how many chunks were created? Creating many chunks will affect performance negatively.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you are creating timestamps that are milliseconds apart. That would explain why you only have one chunk. The default chunk size is 7 days. In this case you probably want to set the partitions smaller to something like a few seconds. You can change the chunk size with: SELECT set_chunk_time_interval('kt_device_info', 4000);